# Change layout if orientation change, error with buttons

Tags: android, onconfigurationchanged

I used `onConfigurationChanged` method to know when the orientation change. But, when I call other layout the buttons not working.

here is my code:

**IntroPage.java**

```
package com.example.mysqltest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IntroPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnlogin;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.intropage);


        btnlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin); 

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    // Check screen orientation or screen rotate event here
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.intropage);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen for landscape and portrait
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.intropage_landscape);
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }   




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(IntroPage.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(i);


    }



    }
```

and i write `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in my manifest xml. Please someone help me...What I can do with buttons not working?

Comment: Should it be android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Comment: yes but the configChange works fine, the layouts change but the buttons not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is not the recommended way to handle this, a quick suggestion would be to add these two lines again after you do `setContentView(R.layout.intropage_landscape);`

```
btnlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin); 
btnlogin.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Recommended way is:

1. Not to call `setContentView` for each orientation. Call `setContentView` once in `onCreate` and initialize all the UI elements.
2. Then re-use the common UI elements for both orientation
3. If there are some non common UI elements, then use fragments to add and remove as necessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: whitch is the recommended way to do this...i try before this two lines  that you suggest and working, but i have too much complicate code(duplicate lines). you suggest better solution?

Comment: have edited my answer suggested a better solution. Please accept the answer if it helps your situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to have notification about orientation changes but keep different layouts for different orientations. The problem in your code is obvious - setContentView sets new ui objects and removes old ones with their clicklisteners.
 Suggestions :
- remove configChanges flag from your activity - so your activity will be created each time after rotation,
- in your onCreate [get current screen orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663665/how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation), compare with previous value (stored in savedInstanceState)
- and save it in [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)(onCreate will receive saved bundle after orientation change);
- also put activity layout xml files for [different orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations).