# How to detect screen flip on Android in Kivy?

Tags: python, event-handling, kivy, flip, screen-rotation

For an app that i'm developing i need to detect when the screen is flipped. I thought of something like `on_pause()` or `on_start()` that resides in the main application class, but I found nothing about it.

Any suggestions?

thanks

---

**updates:**

As suggets @jligeza i tried to add `on_rotate` as follow:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
class guiApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        ## Bind android flip-screen
        def _on_flip_screen(ee):
            print "flipping"
        Window.bind(on_rotate=_on_flip_screen)
```

but this do nothing (no print showed when screen rotate).

I also tried it with `on_flip`but with this event the app crash at start.

No good solution for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a function to `on_rotate` event of the [Window](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase) class.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

def on_window_rotate(obj, degrees):
    print 'rotated degrees:', degrees

Window.bind(on_rotate=on_window_rotate)
```

Comment: Thank jligeza. I notice that in the window class there is an on_flip() event. There is any difference between this and on_rotate?

Comment: @Tungsteno It's something related to OpenGL, I'm not sure what exactly it does.

Comment: I just tested both, but it seems that do not work. on_flip crash the app. :(

Comment: I putted it on the on_start method of my main app class. Is it correct?

Comment: @Tungsteno If it doesn't work then maybe try binding to Window height or width.

Comment: @Tungsteno Another option (which will surely work) is calling a java class to get the orientation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663665/how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation

Comment: I prefer to stay in python environment.

Comment: That java class call is probably the right way to do it, and I don't think it's wrapped in a python api yet (e.g. in [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer)). You'd call it from python with pyjnius, not actually write any java. Feel free to propose a PR to plyer's orientation facade that would add this functionality.