# How to get Android device orientation when launch the app

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation, device-orientation

I tried this, not work, I always got 0 degree

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int screenOrientation = display.getRotation();
```

If use SensorManager, it is also not work, because it will not be triggered if I don't move the phone

```
mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
    }
};
```

---

Update

Please try the complete demo

https://github.com/sochap/getorientationquestdemo

Since the display is not changed, use display to determine that is impossible

I am going to get device orientation, not display orientation

`OrientationEventListener` will work, but not at `onCreate`

Comment: check the screen orientation write this code in oncreate "if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //Landscape mode 
        }" and if you want to check then you can check by portrait mode also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current screen orientation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663665/how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation)

Comment: You can check when the screen orientation changed by overriding onOrientationChaged in Activity

Comment: getResources().getConfiguration().orientation is always 1

Comment: It is impossible to use display to determine, just try my demo

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you. try this.

```
 Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                     // set Values for landscape

 } else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

                   // set Values for portrait
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
     //do something
} else {
     //do something
}
```