# How to change screen on rotation

Tags: java, android

I would like to change the View(to new xml with activity) when I rotate the screen on android studio.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `layout-land` directory and put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory.

Comment: but how can I create activity class for that xml file?

Comment: why would you want to do that? why not have some sort of `if(landScape) doThis() else doThat()` structure?

Comment: how do i do that in activity? how do i check if the screen is rotated or not?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663665/how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation/21909327#21909327

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: welcome, accept the answer?